# Insecure bluetooth connectivity in android app(API Level 8)

Tags: android, bluetooth, insecure-connection

I am developing an android game(Target API - 8)  which can be played from two android mobiles via bluetooth.  Since my app is targeted to API level 8 (android version 2.2) , I cannot go for Insecure connection. But I don't want to have the user intervention for pairing the devices. I found several answers pointing to http://mobisocial.stanford.edu/news/2011/03/bluetooth-reflection-and-legacy-nfc/ . But is this really working? Some people have commented on the blog that it's still not working for them. Is there any better solution available?

Comment: Yes! it does work and I think that's the only hope for you to get insecure connection

Comment: I agree with Waqas, but be forewarned that insecure Bluetooth connectivity has a bug in ICS:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29039

Comment: Ok. I think I should proceed with that option. But I have one concern here. In my app I am not separating the connections (secure & insecure as in BluetoothChat Demo). I will make only one connection all the time and I will use the below statements for the same (as mentioned in the blog)

tmp = InsecureBluetooth.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(mAdapter, NAME, MY_UUID, true);

and

tmp   = InsecureBluetooth.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(device, MY_UUID, true);
.

Will it cause any other issue ??? .. Is it safe to do so ??. I mean other than ICS, will it work on all other versions ??